# APTANA: What are JS Breakpoints and why they are in a PHP file class?

Tags: aptana

I'm working on a php project based on Joomla! and i'm using Aptana.
I'm writing the classes for the component and in the Aptana's editor i've noticed that there is a small blue dot close to the line number at class declaration line.

Pointing on it Aptana tells me the following message

> JS Breakpoint [/path/to/myfile.php, line: ##]

But in my class there is non JS code but only php.

Why Aptana tells me this message? How can i adjust the Aptana's settings to better handle this type of messages?

Thanks a lot,
Adamo "Aerendir"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the same blue dot and message in my Aptana PHP project.  Double-clicking the line number places or removes these breakpoints.  In my case I must have accidentally created the breakpoint while clicking on the folding buttons.

So to answer your question, the breakpoint is there because you created one and you can remove  it by double clicking on the blue dot or line number.

I hope this helps improve your Aptana experience. I have been using Aptana for about 4 months and wish I discovered it a lot sooner.